# Voicelines by character breakdown of Persona 4?

Tags: persona-4

I'm debating about whether to play japanese audio or english audio as there are some voice actors I like on different languages and was wondering if anybody happened to know the percentages of voice lines based on character out of the main cast of playable characters for Persona 4.

Comment: Most story based cutscenes are voiced. Both English and Japanese voice actors in P4 are fantastic. Not sure you're going to get an answer on the percentage, but there is a lot of story in P4 and most of it is voiced.

Comment: @FoxMcCloud yeah I'm looking for the breakdown to try and see how much I'd get of which voice actors I prefer and which ones I dislike to better pick.